# How to copy Numeric Array from parquet to postgres using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are trying to copy the parquet file from blob to Postgres table. Now the problem is my source parquet has some columns with number arrays which ADF is complaining to be not supported, if I change that to string datatype my Postgres say that it is expecting Number Array

Is there some solution or workaround to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for the problem would be to change the type of those columns from array type to string in your Postgres table. This can be done using the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <column_name> TYPE text;
```

I have taken a sample table `player` consisting of 2 array columns `position` (integer array) and `role` (text array).

[image]

After changing the type of these columns, the table looks like this.

```
ALTER TABLE player1 ALTER COLUMN position TYPE varchar(40);

ALTER TABLE player1 ALTER COLUMN role TYPE varchar(40);
```

[image]

You can now complete the copy activity in ADF without getting any errors.

If there are any existing records, the specific array type values will be converted to string type, and it also helps you complete the copy activity without any errors. The following is an example of this case.

- Initial table data (array type columns): https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ErV.png
- Convert to String type: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy69B.png
- After using ADF copy activity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8pFg.png

**NOTE:**

- Considering you have changed the array column to string type in the source file, if you can make changes such that the list of values are enclosed within `{}` rather than `[]`, then you can convert the column type back to array type using `ALTER` query.
- If list of elements are enclosed within `[]` and you try to convert the columns back to array type in your table, it throws the following error.

```
    ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[1,1,0]"
    DETAIL:  Missing "]" after array dimensions.
```